# Why did they need a water tank to transport the humpback whales back to the future?

Tags: star-trek, the-voyage-home

In *The Voyage Home*, Kirk and crew spent so much time on past Earth only because of unavailability of a strong water tank. They even messed with the history which could be dangerous.

But, the question is: Why did they need a water tank in the first place? Whales are mammals which can breathe without water. Only their movements would have been compromised for a short time.

Comment: As far as I know those stranded whales suffer - a lot. Even though technically possible for a short duration, you might as well ask why they let dr taylor on the ship and not tie her to the exterior with some space suit. And if anything goes wrong they end up with a dead whale. But Maybe ask over at biology?

Comment: and why did it have to be transparent?

Comment: The water tank wan't made from transparent aluminum, but from some strong 20th century material. Scotty trades the formula fro transparent aluminum for the material to build the tank.

Comment: I believe animals of that size of incapible of surviving their own weight out of water

Comment: “Only their movements would have been compromised for a short time.” Try telling Dr. Gillian Taylor that.

Comment: @ths - The tank was made of perspex. They traded the formula for transparent aluminium to the inventor of transparent aluminium in return for several large sheets of clear plastic.

Comment: Worth mentioning that they were bringing the whales back to speak on the planets behalf. Probably best to make them as comfortable as possible for the journey so they don't just say, "Yeah, humans suck. Nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure. "

Comment: If a human needs a quick travel to the future to save the whales, why wouldn't they want to be submerged into a large recipient of water until they reach the destination. After all, their ability to breathe would have been compromised for only a short amount of time... (Assuming whales can drive a space ship...)

Comment: @Nasha I'm pretty sure the reason they got into this mess is because a bunch of whales piloting a space ship showed up.

Comment: Why does the whale tank have to be transparent?  ths asked.  And that still hasn't been answered.  Scotty originally wanted transparent aluminum, even though most bulkheads and decks on starships are not made of anything transparent. Scotty eventually settled on some thick transparent plastic, but why was that preferable to opaque steel or opaque plastic?

Comment: Great question!!  Also in the movie you don't see any air at the top of the tank so the whales could have died in transit, depending on how long a whale can go without surfacing to breathe

Comment: No inherent need for the tank to have the quality of being transparent. Scotty needed a material of a certain thickness to fit in the Klingon hold and it had to have a particular strength to hold the water pressure. Spock mentally ran the calculations and surmised that transparent aluminum just happened to fit the bill nicely and could potentially be available.

Comment: Related https://screenrant.com/star-trek-transparent-aluminum-real/

Comment: @KenBanks Humpback whales usually surface every 15 minutes or so, but can remain underwater for 45 minutes.  I can imagine they might actually survive a little bit longer than that, but much.  Even sperm whales can only manage a couple of hours.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Inertial dampers aren't that reliable

Without water, a zero-gravity environment would still have been dangerous for the whales.

In the absence of water, the whales would have needed null gravity within their chamber to keep from collapsing under their own weight.  Without water to hold them in place, the whales would then have been vulnerable to buffeting.  Even gentle maneuvering of the ship could drive two unsecured, multi-tonne squishy masses into the bulkheads, and the slingshot around the sun involved extreme acceleration and potentially violent maneuvering.  As *Star Trek* has shown numerous times when bridge crews are thrown about, ships' [inertial dampers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inertial_damper) can reliably cope with steady acceleration but not with sudden lurches.

Around the midpoint of [the previous film](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_III:_The_Search_for_Spock), *Enterprise* attacks the same Klingon Bird-of-Prey.  The Klingon bridge crew are jostled in their seats, and their reactions seem out of proportion to the bridge console explosions, which suggests that the entire ship is lurching:

In ["Redemption, Part 1"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Redemption_(episode)), a rebel Klingon vessel fires a torpedo at Gowron's flagship.  The impact shakes Gowron (foreground, seated) and nearly knocks a standing bridge officer (background) to the deck.  As the attack proceeds, the flagship continues to shake:

In [*The Voyage Home*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home), Scotty undoubtedly could have cobbled together some sort of active restraint system using tractor beam emitters, but he was working with a limited supply of equipment and an unfamiliar programming interface.  Water, as a passive restraint, was the safest option.

Comment: As *Star Trek* has shown numerous times ... on Federation starships. Do they ever show similar engineering faults in a Klingon warbird?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm pretty confident you can find some examples in DS9, though I don't know off-hand for sure.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I bet you could find some in A Matter of Honor (TNG).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - I added a video clip from *The Search for Spock*. It looks to me as if the Klingons are being shaken, not just startled by the explosions, but I admit that it's not clear.  I'll try to find a better example.

Comment: @jpmc26: Forget Klingon vessels, I'm pretty sure DS9 has at least one *Jem'hadar* screen shake, and their tech is way more advanced than any mere Alpha Quadrant power.

Comment: That's the scene where the Klingon's pet dies.  Ballsack, nooooooOOoooo!

Comment: Sentient whales floating around in null gravity, using their flippers to navigate in the air? Move over, silly humans, in space there's a new dominant species.

Answer (score 53):

According to [this website](http://www.whalefacts.org/why-cant-whales-survive-on-land/), whales need water to:

- Support their weight and prevent their own organs from collapsing in on themselves.
- regulate body temperature / prevent overheating.
- remain hydrated.
- Movement (as you already pointed out, though not really relevant in a tank the size of a fish-bowl).
- Food consumption (again, not very relevant here).

Comment: A whale out of water can't fully inflate their lungs, their lungs fill with fluid and they drown in a matter of hours. Even if something the size of a fully grown humpback survives stranding for 6-12hours, there's no guarantee they'll fully recover from the experience.

Comment: In short, because it's the safest way to do it.

Comment: Also imagine how the whales would have felt after such torture, they would probably tell the probe to obliterate their awful human taxi drivers

Comment: The "prevent overheating" seems particularly important, but I'm guessing it could be compensated for by not heating their chamber as much as you would for a human. Two of the other issues could be handled by turning off the artificial gravity in their chamber.

Answer (score 5):

In short, it's because Kirk doesn't know how long their return journey will take. There's an extra piece of the dialogue (between Kirk and Scott) missing from the film that was apparently in the early shooting script and made it into the [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home_(novel))

> "Humpback whales. They're fifteen or sixteen meters in length. They'll
> mass about forty tons."
>
> "They willna have much room to swim."
>
> **"It doesn't matter. They won't have to stay in the hold for long. I hope."**

While Kirk is hoping they'll have a short uneventful trip back to the future he's anticipating the possibility that something will go wrong and they may end up spending more than a few hours with the whales in the hold, something [that would be catastrophic for their health](https://compbio.imascientist.org.uk/2014/03/19/how-long-would-a-whale-survive-without-any-water-surrounding-it/)

Comment: This quote explains the reason why it doesn't matter to Kirk that the tank is small as being that he hopes the trip will be short.  I don't take it to mean that they're using a water tank because the trip might be long, although it doesn't preclude that possibility.

Comment: @DarrenRinger - The "I hope" is the key phrase here.

Comment: While I agree that Kirk clearly indicates he's planned for the possibility of a longer trip, nowhere from the quoted passage am I able to infer that this is the reason for using a water tank in the first place.  As I read it, the necessity of a tank for a trip of any duration is a foregone conclusion by both parties and left unexplained.

Comment: @DarrenRinger - There's also the fact that Kirk isn't an expert in whales. He knows that they're aquatic and assumes that they'll need a big tank filled with water to transport them.

Answer (score 1):

Counterpoint, unsupported (as far as I know) by canon:  It's for the **acoustical** properties.

One might recall that the whole point of kidnapping the whales in the first place was to get them to respond to an alien message.

Putting the whales into a water medium is important for both the whales' ability to hear and understand the message and for their ability to respond vocally.

As sensible as this seems to me and real-world physics, I don't think it has any actual canon support.

Comment: This answer makes zero sense. The water was to transport them safely on the ship, not to allow them to hear the alien probe while they were in space.